# Which service/s can be used to store and stream VR content for an app?

Tags: android, ios, virtual-reality

I am a new developer and I want to develop a VR app which streams content from online database. Can you tell me which services (Firebase, AWS etc.) are best to use for this purpose for database and streaming that can work both on Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean streaming VR 360 video content, or streaming just regular 'flat' video or audio, then the usual HTTP and HLS and MPEG DASH streaming technologies will work in the VR domain, although for VR 360 video you need to have a player that recognises the extra projection information or else your video will be presented as a flat 'fish eye' view.

If you mean synchronising on device objects or elements in the world with other players on other devices then it is almost certainly going to be best to build on a framework that does this. One example, probably the most common, is the Unity framework - see some info on their multi player networking here:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetGameObjects.html